# JSDoc, treat POJO as instance of Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jsdoc

I have a class and a function that takes instance of that class *or a similar POJO object* as argument.

I want to annotate this function using JSDoc.

```
class Test {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

/**
 * @param {Test} test
 */
function handleTest(test) {
    console.log(test.a, test.b);
}

// Webstorm complains that argument is not of type Test
handleTest({
    a: 'this is a'
});
```

Using `@param {Test} test` *almost* works... but WebStorm complains that POJO isn't assignable to type Test.

Is there some JSDoc trick I can do to make it clear that both instance of `Test` and a `Test`-like object are both OK?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**type union**](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html):

```
/**
 * @param {Test|{a,b}} test
 */
function handleTest(test) {
  console.log(test.a, test.b);
}
```

The `|{a,b}` part of the type denotes separate allowable types. You *could* just use `{Test|{}}` but then the IDE doesn't know that `a` and `b` are expected properties.

That's the shorthand version; you could also define what "Test-like" objects are in case you plan on using and documenting TestLike objects in more than one place:

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} TestLike
 * @property {string} a - some property a
 * @property {string} b - some property b
 */

/**
 * @param {Test|TestLike} test
 */
handleTest(test) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then I'd have to annotate duplicates of all objects - once in comments, once in class. The whole point is to be able to use the Class as annotation, so when Class changes, IDE will warn me my function calls are wrong.

Comment: Understand what you are saying, but I'm not sure of a way to get 100% there